# Adding DestinationConnectionOLEDB in subject of SSIS send email task

Tags: ssis

We have a package on Server A which we use to load the data into different databases on different Servers. We just change the destination Connection through "SQL Server 2008 Integration Services Package Execution Utility". When the package loads the data it sends a confirmation Email with a subject of "package name and time" that data has been loaded successfully. I want to add the destination connection (Server name and database name) in the subject to make sure the data is loading into the right destination.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a script task to load the information into a variable.

I am assuming that if you are dynamically setting your connection that you have the connection string stored as a variable.

If so you can use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder() class in .net.

```
var connstring = DTS.Variables["Yourvariablehere"].Value.ToString();
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connstring);
DTS.Variables["servervariablehere"].Value = builder.DataSource;
DTS.Variables["databasevariablehere"].Value = builder.InitialCatalog;
```